# iOS AdMob memory leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, admob, automatic-ref-counting

I just started using `AdMob` but I noticed that, after running it for about an hour, it's accumulated 50MB! Yikes. I thought about releasing it but I can't since I am using  `ARC`. Any ideas? I'm using the getting started code provided by google:

```
GADBannerView *bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(self.scroller.frame.origin.x,self.scroller.frame.origin.y + 70,self.scroller.frame.size.width,self.scroller.frame.size.height);
[self.scroller setFrame:newFrame];

bannerView_.adUnitID = @"XXXXX";
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;

[bannerView_ setFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                 20,
                                 bannerView_.bounds.size.width,
                                 bannerView_.bounds.size.height)];

[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Comment: why not dealloc the object i.e bannerView_ = nil;

Comment: But then I would lose the ad on my screen? I need to keep it going without losing memory.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think Christophe is right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

When receiving a new ad, you must remove the previous ad from the parent view.

Otherwise, they are superimposed on each other and consumes memory.

So, after receiving more than 15 advertisements, the percentage of allocated memory remained constant.

Hoping that this will help you.

```
- ( void )displayBanner:( UIView * )banner
{    
    UIView * oldBanner = [ _bannerView viewWithTag:999 ];

    if( oldBanner )
    {
       [ oldBanner removeFromSuperview ];
       oldBanner = nil;
    }

    banner.tag = 999;
    [ _bannerView addSubview:banner ];
}
```

Comment: but where would you call this methode @christophe? and what is this UIView because the GADBannerView *_bannerView dosn't require any aditional view. @Dilisqq can you maybe tell me your solution cause i have the same problem currently.

Comment: @Zero3nna Hi! I never got around to using Christphe's answer as digging around more I realized I was doing it all wrong. The leak only persists if you instantiate more than 1 instance of the GADBanner. What I did instead to be able to present the ads across multiple screens was to create a `StaticSingleton` object that instantiated the GadBanner and passed it along to the different views that I had as I segued into them.

Comment: In my specific case, the private method ** - (Void) displayBanner :( UIView *)  banner ** is used in response to the delegate method: ** - (Void) adViewDidReceiveAd GADBannerView :( *) view**. _bannerView is a instance of an uiview which I use as container to display ads and I realized that all ads was stacked in my internal view after each call of adViewDidReceiveAd.
But this does not correct the problem. I get a lot of MemoryWarning when I use AdMob and I received numerous negative reviews because of it. I'll test the Dilisqq solution (Singleton).

Comment: so will I. @christophe here is a starting point if you not already know this post: http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.de/2012/04/creating-gadbannerview-singleton-in.html

Comment: Thank you, I will try this later. But I'm not sure that this a solution to AdMob memory leak...

Comment: @Christophe Admob is also creating memory leaks for me. Did that ^^ work?

Comment: @Minestroni-Soup My app is used in 45 countries worldwide with adMob. So, yes, I can say that this works for me.

Comment: @Christophe Just to clarify, did you use the accepted solution, or a StaticSingleton?

Comment: @ Minestroni-Soup Singleton or not, this is not the meaning of the question. For me the problem was that the banner was not removed from my host view. Just remember to remove the view by calling removeFromSuperview to free memory.