# iOS - Admob Memory Leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, admob

I have already looked at these questions which did not work for me:

- [iOS AdMob memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397119/ios-admob-memory-leak/27020044?noredirect=1#comment63118410_27020044)
- [ADMOB Memory Leaking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24983500/admob-memory-leaking)

I am currently having memory leaks which causes my app to begin at 30 megabytes, instead of the usual 10, and increase in 10 megabytes every so often. I have confirmed that the cause of the memory leaks are due to Admob, but I can only assume that the other memory leaks are due to another ad loading. I have looked at [this google discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/ios/F3wQOExzsjc) which suggests that this is due to `SKPaymentQueue` in the `StoreKit` framework. You can see this also happens to me:

[image]

What I find even more odd, is that when I delete the `StoreKit` framework from my project, nothing changes.

This is how I implemented Admob for my app:

1. Downloaded version 7.8.1 of the SDK
2. Added the GoogleMobileAds, StoreKit, AudioToolbox, AdSupport, CoreGraphics, CoreTelephony, EventKit, EventKitUI, MessageUI, SystemConfiguration, and AVFoundation frameworks.
3. Created a GADBannerView in Storyboard
4. Linked to h file which imported GoogleMobileAds
5. m file - `viewDidLoad`:

   ```
   self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
   self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;

   GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

   request.testDevices = @[kGADSimulatorID];

   [self.bannerView loadRequest:request];
   ```

My question is whether there is something wrong with my implementation, or whether others are experiencing this problem due to `StoreKit` and if there's a work around.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem! Have you solved it?

Comment: @NJanf Not really. I DO get memory leaks that cause a sudden spike in memory, but after some more testing, I found that eventually the memory gets cleared up. Very odd.

Comment: Same thing happens to me. Memory increases every time a new ad loads - without doing anything (app is idle) the memory increases. I also see see the memory leaks for SKPaymentQueue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I see a lot of people looking at this question, and I do get some upvotes, so here's what I discovered. They Are memory leaks that cause increases in memory, but after a while, the memory will be released.